# How to change keyboard layout in windows console CMD or WSL?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, powershell-4.0, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I open CMD in Windows 10, I get the wrong keyboard layout. 
Same with WSL (bash)

When powershell is used, it displays the correct one.

This is a screenshot when pressing the `;` key in a standard US keyboard layout.

I have no idea how to change it, there's nothing in settings for the console.

[image: Wrong keyboard]

Edit:

This is the result of command:

`Get-WinUserLanguageList | Format-Table -Property LanguageTag, InputMethodTips`

```
Get-WinUserLanguageList | Format-Table -Property LanguageTag, InputMethodTips

LanguageTag InputMethodTips
----------- ---------------
en-US       {0409:00000409}
es-MX       {080A:0000080A}
```

This is the result of command `chcp` in both cmd and powershell:
`Active code page: 850`

I tried `chcp 437` as suggested by @IoCalisto but didn't work

**SOLVED**

Problem vanished when autohotkey was turned off.

For some reason, autohotkey doesn't work properly with CMD or WSL for some mappings.

Comment: [This layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/kbdus_7.html) with _semicolon_ right to *Latin Small Letter L*? Read the [_Keyboard scancodes_](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html)  article as well.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output from `Get-WinUserLanguageList | Format-Table -Property LanguageTag, InputMethodTips`

Answer (score 5):

To change keyboard layout to Arabic:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList  ar-eg, en-US -force
```

To change keyboard layout to English:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList  en-US, ar-EG -force
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to launch wsl through powershell (by simply typping wsl in it) as it detects the keyboard layout succesfully.

Answer (score -2):

This may be an issue with code page number? 
Try typing chcp (without arguments) into cmdline and see what is returned (The code page number for US is 437).
To set the code page number, type chcp follwoed by the CPN you would like to use
example:

```
chcp 437
```

all windows code page numbers can be found here (to my knowledge):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Hope this helps

Comment: @lalo May I ask what language your system is in? You could try changing the winCPN to your local language and/or trying to find a keyboard from your area.

Another suggestion is to head on over to the Autohotkey section of SO and learn about key re-mapping

Comment: @lalo Also, did the CPN stick? Or was it replaced again by 850?

Comment: I used chcp 437 and confirmed that it stick as 437
but `;` still gives me `<`

HOWEVER, I found the answer. 
when I turned off autohotkey, problem vanished. 

weird that CMD doesn't work fine with autohotkey!